# Running a file on vbs with administrator rights

Tags: vbscript, admin

I am new to VBS, and this is what I am trying to achieve :
Running a driver installation file with administrator rights in a non-admin account. I understand you can do something like:

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
If WScript.Arguments.length = 0 Then
  Set ObjShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
  ObjShell.ShellExecute "wscript.exe", """" & _
  WScript.ScriptFullName & """" &_
  " RunAsAdministrator", , "runas", 1
End if

CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "program.exe"
```

But it prompts for the admin username and password. I do not want that. How do I do it in such a way that the VBS provides the admin username and password and the rights to run the program?

Thank you!

Comment: That would defeat the purpose of not giving the user admin rights in the first place.

Comment: This script is meant to only give a one time admin right for a driver update.

Comment: Drivers run with elevated privileges. If you're giving someone the right to update drivers, you can just as well make them admins. It's better to use a software deployment system for rolling out driver (or other software) updates.